# C# confusion on neccessity of explicit type conversion in class hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

I have two classes `Vector` and `Point`, where `Point` is subclass of `Vector`. I have a method `Scale` for `Vector`s (and thus for `Point`s too) and a method `Clone` for `Point`s that returns a deep copy.

```
public class Vector
{
    protected double x, y, z;

    public Vector(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }

    public Vector Scale(double sc)
    {
        this.x = sc * x; this.y = sc * y; this.z = sc * z;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Point : Vector
{
    public Point(double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y, z) { }

    public Point Clone()
    {
        return new Point(this.x, this.y, this.z);
    }
}
```

(Note: The actual code is more complex than this, with a lot more methods, but this excerpt should suffice to illustrate the problem. Please do not suggest any changes in the inheritance hierarchy or turning the classes into structs. I have evaluted those questions with my colleagues already.)

Now I write the following into my main program:

```
Point p = new Point(1, 2, 3);
Point q = p.Clone().Scale(2); // compile error complaining about missing cast
```

The second line can be fixed by this:

```
Point q = p.Clone().Scale(2) as Point;
```

But my problem is that I do not understand why this is necessary.
This is what I THOUGHT the compiler does:

`p` is a `Point`. `p.Clone()` is another `Point`. We check if there exists a method `Point.Scale(double)`. We cannot find one, so we check if the superclass has such a method, i.e. if a method `Vector.Scale(double)` exists. We look into `Vector.Scale` and we find that it returns `this`. Since `p.Clone()` is a `Point`, we know that the return value of `p.Clone().Scale(2)` will be `p.Clone()` itself (but modified), so it must be a `Point`. Voila, no cast necessary.

- So what is the problem, why can't the compiler not infer that I do not need any cast?
- How do I fix it such that a user does not have to cast every time? Is the only way to achieve this to write a method `Point.Scale(double)`? I know I can make it a one-liner by redirecting to `Vector.Scale(double)`, but I will have extra cost because of the additional documentation comment for the new method, so this is not desirable.
- Is this cast just a formism such that the compiler does not complain, or will there actually be done anything internally? I mean anything like shifting around memory or allocating/deallocating memory, or any calculations?

Comment: `Scale` returns `Vector` and you try to assign it `Point`; you can implcitly cast `Point` to `Vector`, but not `Vector` to `Point`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the inferred type is the return type of the last executed function (the rightmost one, or the `Scale()` method in your case which returns a `Vector` and not a `Point`)

---

To not have to cast each time you'd wanted to call the scale method, you could use generics.

One example would be :

```
public abstract class Scalable<T>
{
    protected double x, y, z;

    public T Scale(double sc)
    {
        this.x = sc * x; this.y = sc * y; this.z = sc * z;
        return this;
    }

    public Scalable(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }
}
```

That class would define what is needed to make an object scalable, it is defined as abstract so that the developper can't create an instance of that class, only inherit from it.

Your other two classes would then change accordingly :

```
public class Vector : Scalable<Vector>
{
    public Vector(double x, double y, double z) : base(x,y,z)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Point : Scalable<Point>
{
    public Point(double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y, z) { }

    public Point Clone()
    {
        return new Point(this.x, this.y, this.z);
    }
}
```

Another simpler method would simply be to define a scale method which calls the Vector one and cast in one go :

```
public class Point : Vector
{
    public Point(double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y, z) { }

    public Point Clone()
    {
        return new Point(this.x, this.y, this.z);
    }

    public Point Scale(double sc)
    {
        return (Point)base.Scale(sc);
    }
}
```

---

And for your third question :

The compiler do not know what you are doing inside the method, it only knows what type is returned.

As such, it cannot guarantee that the returned object can be converted into the `Point` object.

The cast you have to write is here to tell the compiler : "Don't worry, I know this object IS of the  type I've indicated you"

Comment: So there is no (even minimal) performance penalty when doing such a cast?

Comment: There is no performance penalty when casting AFAIK, you might get some performance hit using keywords such as `as` for casting or `is` for checking type, since it will start reflecting on the object to detect it's type.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the return type of `Scale` to be `dynamic` (depending on availability of your compiler):

```
public dynamic Scale(double sc)
{
    this.x = sc * x; this.y = sc * y; this.z = sc * z;
    return this;
}
```

See comments below for issues.

Comment: and then you loose all type safety with the returned object :p

Comment: That's true. I agree it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The Scale method returns a Vector object. You cannot assign a Vector object to a Point reference. Point inherits from Vector.

Furthermore, I would suggest you to work with structs and not with classes. Then you won't need the Clone method.

Comment: The complete `Vector` and `Point` classes have a lot more methods, and I need them to be mutable to avoid allocating memory for every calculation. E.g. multiplying a vector by a matrix is not supposed to return a new vector, since the original one will not always be needed and can as well be overwritten. If the old vector must be kept, we can use `Clone` (wich I also implemented in `Vector`).

Comment: @Kjara I'd recommend you to add these precisions in your question so that people understands taht these classes are only example ones and the real ones are a little more complicated than that ;)